# Memory size exceeded while sending data in Azure Eventhub using python code

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

ValueError: EventDataBatch has reached its size limit: 1048576

I am using below code
[image]

Comment: each message can be up to 1MB only in Azure Event Hub, see doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas

Comment: It's important to note that more than the event body is counted in the size; there is also some overhead that needs to be reserved for the AMQP message format and for injection of distributed tracing metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use the add method to add events until the maximum batch size limit in
> bytes has been reached - at which point a ValueError will be raised.

As per the above statement from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.eventdatabatch?view=azure-python), the events you have added in batch has exceeded the maximum size limit which is 1 MB.

[image]

**Make sure that the batch must contain the events' size upto 1MB only.**